# How can the intersection of CFLs and REGs be CFL if REG is a proper subset of CFL?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, chomsky-hierarchy

Intersection of CFL and regular is always CFL. But according to Chomsky hierarchy diagram, regular languages lie **completely inside CFL**.  So, as regular set is completely inside CFL set, their intersection should be regular right ?

Am I interpreting Chomsky diagram wrongly ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you are misinterpreting stuff.

The set of languages (DFL, regular, ...) and the set of strings in a language are independent.

It is entirely possible that a regular language contains strings that are not inside a Context free language.

The trivial example is where the regular language is all strings $\Sigma^*$ and the CFL is any other language. The intersection between them is the original CFL.

Comment: In this diagram https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTv4mMFXhUfF6l6-Ms8FE9nlDdV2NJic-gDwiQ2c8l6jOuaq609hTPrZe06. Regular language is subset of CFL. So according to subset property of sets , any set's intersection with it's subset is the subset itself right (which is regular) ?

Comment: But each language is a set of strings so when talking about the intersection between 2 languages you are talking about intersecting the *set of strings*. That is independent from the set of languages.

Comment: Ok so Chomsky hierarchy says intersection of **set of all CFL's** and **set of all Regular languages** is **set of regular languages** right?

Answer (score 11):

You are confusing two different statements.

1. $\mathrm{CFL} \cap \mathrm{REG} = \mathrm{REG}$ or, equivalently,
    for all $L_1 \in \mathrm{REG}$ : $L_1 \in \mathrm{CFL}$.
2. For all $L_1 \in \mathrm{REG}$, $L_2 \in \mathrm{CFL}$ : $L_1 \cap L_2 \in \mathrm{CFL}$.

The first makes a statement on two sets of languages (aka language classes), the second makes one over (many) pairs of sets of strings (aka languages). So in mixing the two, you are creating a type error.

Also, you seem to suggest that if a language is context-free, it's not regular. That is false; we have $\mathrm{REG} \subsetneq \mathrm{CFL}$ (cf. 1.), so showing a language is CFL (using 2.) does not preclude it from being regular. Specifically, it's easy to find examples of a non-regular context-free and a regular language whose intersection is regular.

Comment: Very clear distinction between the two statements, but which one is correct?  (I know they're not mutually exclusive, but if I understood the other answer correctly, only one of them happens to be true.)

Comment: Both are true. The false one is $\forall L_1 \in REG, L_2 \in CFL: L_1 \cap L_2 \in REG$.